# d3 node labeling: how to display JSON data formatted with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

How to display JSON data formatted with HTML in d3 node label?

HTML formatting is different for each label:

```
"nodes": [
    {
      "group": 3,
      "id": "école féminin ou masculin",
      "label": "école <b>féminin ou masculin</b>"
    }
]
```

This does not work, what is between the  tags is not displayed while in the source code it appears:

```
var text = node.append('text').html(function(d) {return d.label;});
```

Source code result:

```
<g class="nodes">
    <circle r="25" style="fill: rgb(102, 193, 163); /*! touch-action: none; */" cx="417.29708547093924" cy="425.4471792945814"></circle>
    <text x="417.29708547093924" y="425.4471792945814">école <b>féminin ou masculin</b></text>
</g>
```

What is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Use [foreignObject](http://web.archive.org/web/20120418122612/http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the structure of your dataset, then I would suggest using a `text` element with multiple `tspan` elements to style each part of the label differently. Below is a simplified example (if your label styling is more complex than the example you provided, then you would need to modify the below approach to appending the tspans, but this should point you in the right direction).

```js
const nodes = [{
  "group": "3",
  "x": "30",
  "y": "30",
  "id": "école féminin ou masculin",
  "tspans": [
    {"text": "école ", "style": "font-weight: normal;"},
    {"text": "féminin ou masculin", "style": "font-weight: bold;"}
  ]
}];

const svg = d3.select('body')
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', 300)
              .attr('height', 300);

const circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
                   .data(nodes)
                   .enter()
                   .append('circle');
                   
const labels = svg.selectAll('text')
                  .data(nodes)
                  .enter()
                  .append('text');

circles
  .attr('r', 25)
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y)
  .attr('style', 'fill: rgb(102, 193, 163);');
  
labels
  .attr('x', d => d.x)
  .attr('y', d => d.y)
  .append('tspan')
  .text(d => d.tspans[0].text)
  .attr('style', d => d.tspans[0].style);
  
labels
  .append('tspan')
  .text(d => d.tspans[1].text)
  .attr('style', d => d.tspans[1].style);
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for your example. I will apply your advice, indeed, it's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The `text` svg element won't render `html`. In order to render `html` within the `svg`, you'll need to append a `foreignObject` first.

Additionally, the `circle` element can't have any children so you'll need to append the element next to the circle.

Try this:

```js
var nodes = [
    {
      "group": 3,
      "id": "école féminin ou masculin",
      "label": "école <b>féminin ou masculin</b>"
    }
]

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var nodes = svg.selectAll("g").data(nodes);

var node = nodes.enter().append("g");

node
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 25)
  .attr("cx", 30)
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("style", "fill: rgb(102, 193, 163)");

  node
  .append('foreignObject')
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .html(function(d) {return d.label});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a snippet that renders the html properly. Also, keep in mind that a circle svg element can't have any children, so you can't put a `text` element within a circle.

Comment: Thank's for help. it still does not work, I also try locally. here is the rendering of my side. https://ibb.co/k8Bvyo

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? Unfortunately, `foreignObject` is not supported in IE so you'll need to try it in a different browser like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I use Firefox, I also try with Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I've found a other method: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411 and https://gist.github.com/billdwhite/6243279

Comment: The snippet in this answer appears to work and is a very similar approach to the http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411 link you posted in your comment. Are you sure you don't have some conflicting code elsewhere?

Comment: @benvc Yes, I do not have an error in my console. After removing the cache from Chrome it works but still not with Firefox. It's strange!

Comment: You are right. Does not work for me in Firefox either. After some reading, it seems that foreignObject behavior in this context is difficult to pin down across browsers. If you have control over your dataset, I would suggest breaking your "label" data into an array of objects each with their own text and style data. That way you could append your label as a `text` element and then append each label part as a `tspan` with specific style attributes.

Comment: @benvc I'm not sure I understood your tip with tspan, do you have a quick example please? thank's